# How do I find the contentPadding of a InputDecoration?

Tags: flutter

The `InputDecoration` comes with a predetermined `contentPadding` and if I want to just move the contents of the `InputDecoration` a little bit to the left, I will have to override internal `contentPadding`.

Is it there a way for me to find out what's the value of an `InputDecoration` `contentPadding`? I tried the Flutter Inspector, but I can't see anything there at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always Check file source for values - [input_decorator.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/input_decorator.dart#L1880)

[image]

Comment: Well, there are several values, I want to know which one is the one my app has...is it there an easy way? Or will I have to try all of those and see which one matches?

Comment: see it depends on condition - By default the contentPadding reflects `isDense` and the type of the `border`. If `isCollapsed` is true then contentPadding is `EdgeInsets.zero`.

Comment: so from code you can see the conditions - `decoration.isCollapsed` then - `!border.isOutline` & so on match what you have enabled then you get the value.

Comment: Ok, I thought there might be an easy tool for this, thanks!